# Is there a tool to get the ViewState byte count for any of the major browsers?

Tags: webforms, viewstate

I am looking for a tool to give me a byte count of ViewState after each postback (full or partial) to make sure that I'm not keeping any controls' states around unnecessarily.  Is there a tool out there?

Comment: on partial updates the view state isn't sent to the server, only the control state is sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and it's called Viewstate Size.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5956/

Answer (score 2):

If you use fiddler, I recommend you this extension

http://blogs.msdn.com/nexpert/

It gives you information about viewstate size and many other performance items.

If you're not using fiddler... what are waiting for??? :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you add the attribute [`Trace="true"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08.aspx) to your page, it will output debug information including the view state when you browse the site. No plugin is required.

For Internet Explorer there is a plugin called [Web Development Helper](http://projects.nikhilk.net/WebDevHelper/) that shows view state information.